# No consigo detectar xpath en Twitter

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, twitter, selenium-webdriver

Llevo desde ayer intentando en Python, con Selenium, crear un bot que permita votar una encuesta.
El proceso desde iniciar sesión hasta llegar a la votación lo hace perfectamente, pero cuando le indico el xPath de la opción a votar, esta no lo detecta y se cierra el bot.
Probé a externalizar el marco en otra pestaña, pero por un lado tenemos el mismo error, y por el otro, al parecer la encuesta funciona por Tokens, es decir, que aunque se acceda desde el mismo usuario, el enlace al marco caduca cuando se cierra y se abre de nuevo.

Les dejo el extracto del código donde me salta el error por si alguien puede alumbrarme un poco. Un saludo.

```
#Bot entra a encuesta

#entrar encuesta
driver.get("https://twitter.com/majeflomon/status/988357553007550465")
print("----Accediendo a encuesta")

time.sleep(2)

#votar encuesta
button_opc = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/div[2]/label/span[2]")
button_opc.click()
print("----Opcion Marcada (NO)")

#enviar voto
button_env = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div/span[1]")
button_env.click()
print("----Votacion Realizada")
```

Comment: ¿Qué error te salta?

Comment: Y buscar la opción especificando la ruta xpath al elemento no me parece una forma muy flexible. Un mínimo cambio en la estructura ya te causaría un fallo. ¿No tienes algún elemento con un atributo `class` o `id` que puedas especificar para no ser tan dependiente del orden de las cosas?

Comment: @abulafia que va, todo son span (o la ámplia mayoría). El error que me salta es que no detecta ese elemento Selenium. De momento he conseguido hacerlo funcionar usando la versión móvil de Twitter pero no más

Comment: Si, son `span`, pero tienen atributos. Por ejemplo, acabo de ver que los radio-button donde elegir las opciones son de la clase `PollXChoice-choice--radio`. Es mucho más seguro sacar la lista de nodos que tengan ese atributo y luego elegir uno por índice, que especificar la ruta de `div` anidados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buscando encuestas de ese mismo usuario, he visto que las encuestas se encuentran sobre un iframe. Por lo tanto debes cambiar primero al iframe que contiene la encuesta:

```
driver.switch_to.frame("id") 
# Tambien se puede cambiar al iframe por el name
# O pasando una variable de tipo WebElement, localizandola
# previamente por xpath

...

# Una vez realizada la votacion debes volver al contenido principal
# es decir, salir del iframe
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```